# In my last job I wore multiple hats; would it be OK to list separately each role I covered?

Tags: resume, linkedin

In my last job I was working on a software company covering several roles:

- Project Manager for projects A, B, C (e.g. Word, Excel, Powerpoint)
- Product Manager for the main product (e.g. Windows), connecting our work to our customers' needs, working on interfaces and user experience, designing new products and directly contributing to the update of older products
- Team Leader, providing vision, coaching and support to my direct subordinates
- technology expert, providing expertise and hands-on work on almost everything the main product offered (e.g. "creating Word", "creating Excel", "creating Powerpoint"), both to my team and to the rest of the company (remotely)
- sales representative, outreaching potential customers and leveraging my specialised field knowledge to liaise with them and get them onboard ("what kind of Excel do you need? Tell me about your favourite Excel plugin")

Right now I have something like "Senior Developer" on my CV, but I am not sure if it conveys the huge knowledge and expertise I acquired at my last job.

My question is: should I list all these roles separately on my CV and on my other profiles, e.g. LinkedIn?

Comment: Off-topic: I don't mean to take anything off your achievements, but at senior levels in IT, it is quite usual for skilled employees to don multiple hats. on-topic: You are not obliged to list your official designation (such as Senior Developer) in the resume. You can use something which more accurately describes the role you were handling. I can't think of any short phrase that encompasses all your bullets.

Comment: Happy, thanks for your comment. So you are saying that I should use ONE designation, but maybe pick the one more appropriate for the job I am applying for?

Comment: @StackTA42, always use your official title. You will be background checked and could lose the job for lying otherwise. Make the text emphasize the role(s) most pertinenet to the position you are applying for.

Comment: @HLGEM Background check is rarely done directly on the resume data, you are typically asked to fill another form with your work history, and you can enter your official designation there. Moreover, if it worries you that much, you could write the official designation in the resume lower down. I write my resume to stand out, and I am not so sure a "vanilla" designation like Senior Developer helps emphasize the "extra" roles that other Senior Developers may not have played.

Comment: Further, you write your resume to match the job description. If the company is looking for a Software Engineer to design Java applications, and your official designation is "{JavaBasedCompanyProprietaryFrameworkName} Development Professional", your resume is likely to get tossed out so you don't even get to the background check part.

Comment: @Happy I disagree strongly. No one pays much attention to titles in my experience until they do the background check. They are looking for keywords and for descriptions of what you did and accomplishments. But if you say you were a project manager and the HR people say you were a developer, that is a huge negative in the background check.  That doesn't mean you can't describe project managers duties or even put it in () after your offical title. But lying on the resume is the single biggest negative you can have and it can bite you even years later when they find out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Happy points out in the comments, it's common at higher levels to wear multiple hats.  What I would have is something like the following:

Current Role:

xxx-present -  FooCorp Senior Developer

Some general text about the role.  The role had the following accountabilities:

- **Project Manager** - Managed multiple project deliveries, more detail about you in this specific role (but not specific projects keep that for next section)
- **Product Manager** - again
- **Team Lead** - and again

Then have a section with the details of specific projects and what you did.  Depending on the role you are going for, you can re-order or enhance (or remove) any of the bullets to give the required impression.

Comment: I always use my official title as HR will confirm it when they do a background check. If I had other roles I explain inthe text as you have shown.

Comment: @HLGEM - well you can use non-official titles.  I have an employment history section at the end rather than dates inline which has company, start/end and official title.  I combined both for brevity in the answer.  Any background check will look at this.

Comment: I agree with @HLGEM - you can only ever have one job title at any time (unless you are moonlighting elsewhere) - but that job title can cover many responsibilities and duties, and that can (and should) be addressed in the detail below the job title in a resume.